# Betaflight attitude update rate only 100hz?

Tags: betaflight, imu

In the [tasks.c](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/blob/master/src/main/fc/tasks.c) file, this line in particular

```
[TASK_ATTITUDE] = DEFINE_TASK("ATTITUDE", NULL, NULL, imuUpdateAttitude, TASK_PERIOD_HZ(100), TASK_PRIORITY_MEDIUM)
```

If I understood this correctly, attitude is updated at 100hz only by default. Why then do we need gyros which update at 8kHz rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't quite dug into the source code to confirm my suspicions, but this file lends credence to the idea that this task facilitates *accelerometer*-based attitude calculations and not *gyroscope*-based calculations.

From line 274 to line 280 in the file you link to ([tasks.c](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/blob/master/src/main/fc/tasks.c)), the `TASK_ATTITUDE` task is said to be enabled if the accelerometer device is enabled (*in the Betaflight Configurator*):

```
#if defined(USE_ACC)
    if (sensors(SENSOR_ACC) && acc.sampleRateHz) {
        setTaskEnabled(TASK_ACCEL, true);
        rescheduleTask(TASK_ACCEL, TASK_PERIOD_HZ(acc.sampleRateHz));
        setTaskEnabled(TASK_ATTITUDE, true);
    }
#endif
```

Given that these are the only times that the `TASK_ATTITUDE` task is mentioned in this file, I doubt that this 100 Hz task is related to gyroscopic sampling.